# Show Cart Session Item

Tags: php, session

I have successful to display cart and add to cart those thing.
but i wanted to show the cart item list on the payment page to let the user
to confirm their item quantity and prices. how to display them those data in the
session. here is how my coding. Below code is cart.php
i wanted to display item to payment.php

```html
switch($action)
{  
 case "add":
 
   if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$proid]))
   $_SESSION['cart'][$proid]++;
  else
   $_SESSION['cart'][$proid]=1;
 
 break;
 case "remove":
 
  if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$proid]))
  {
   $_SESSION['cart'][$proid]--;
   if ($_SESSION['cart'][$proid]==0)
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$proid]);
  }
 
  else
   $_SESSION['cart'][$proid]=1;
 
 break;
 case "empty" :
 unset($_SESSION['cart']);
 break; 
} 
     
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart']))
    {
     $total = 0;
     foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $proid =>$x)
     {
      $results = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from product where Product_ID = $proid");
      $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
      $productname = $myrow['Product_Name'];
      $productprice= $myrow['Product_Price'];
      $line_cost = $productprice * $x;
      $total=$total+$line_cost;
      ?>
       <li class = "cartlist">
       <?php echo  '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($myrow['Product_Pic']) . '" width="196" height="120">';?>
       <p><span style = "font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">
       <?php echo $productname ?>
       </span></br />RM <?php echo $productprice;?>
       </br />Quantity : <?php echo $x ?></br><a href='cart.php?proid=<?php echo $proid;?>&action=add'>Add </a>&ensp;<a href ='cart.php?proid=<?php echo $proid;?>&action=remove'> Reduce </a></br>RM<?php echo $line_cost; ?> <br/> 
       </p> </li>
      <?php
     }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: Why u want get each time the product from DB instead u can get the product information and store it in session once product is added to cart. Eg: case 'add' : //store product info to session. Can u get my point?

Comment: I suggest you to use PHP Frameworks like CI, it already has a built-in cart library.

Comment: Oh.. I don't know can work like that .. I'll try later

Comment: This is something like an assignment and I not allow to use Cl ~

Comment: The cart pages I can perform normally . The only problem is i cannot display the cart item on payment pages .

Comment: you can not show cart information on payment page (If you are using third party payment method)

Comment: Err.. It's ok .. I'm just doing for an assignment purpose. And doesn't involved any payment method.